# Send multipart/form-data to apex @HttpPost service

Tags: rest-api, apexrest

How I am currently doing this is, sending a raw JSON through Postman. This JSON is used to create a Case record in Salesforce. In order to attach a file to that case, the JSON contains a base64 encoded file content, which could be used for attachment.

When I send a multipart/form-data, postman throws

> You have sent us an Illegal URL or an improperly formatted request.

I also remember reading somewhere that `Apex REST does not support multipart/form-data requests`.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Looking around, I found [**this link**](https://docparser.com/blog/post-file-salesforce-apex-external-http-webservices/), see if that helps.

Comment: What API you are using? Is it standard API or custom API?